# Gradle build failed with an error 'timeout waiting to connect to the Grade daemon'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My new project is displaying this error on first run. I've not changed any project files android creates. Android Studio version 2.2 (Canary build), Gradle version 2.14.1 and plugin version 2.2.0.

> Error: Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>   Cause: Timeout waiting to connect to the Gradle daemon.
>   Daemon uid: c788c7c1-86fc-45e7-9981-345127b657de with diagnostics:
>   Daemon pid: 5044 log file: C:\Users\red\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\daemon-5044.out.log
>   Unable to read from the daemon log file: C:\Users\red\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\daemon-5044.out.log,
>   because of: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
> C:\Users\red\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\daemon-5044.out.log 
> (The system cannot find the file specified)

Note: The app level build.gradle file is not displayed in Gradle scripts. Also the file is not opening within Android Studio. The 'build project' option is not displayed in 'Build' menu (probably because the build was not successful).

Comment: Please clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Rebuild, make project etc are not working (Nothing happens on rebuild project and make project). Clean project results in same error.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I myself have found the solution. After a little search, I've learned that firewall interrupts gradle processes. I turned off Windows firewall and closed antivirus. But still it is not solved. So, I've uninstalled my antivirus and installed Avira. Now everything works fine.

Also earlier when I tried deleting .gradle folder, it said that the folder was being used by other programs. So, I guess some antivirus programs mess with Android files and folders.

Note: Keeping the question for anyone with similar problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. You saved my day. Guys don't search anywhere, if u installed anti-virus please uninstall it. i was using quick heal anti-virus so my problem solved by doing above solution.

Comment: Took days to understand that a f**kin antivirus was muddling my gradle stuff. Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it helped to colse the project and reopen it.